# Entity Framework - entities with inherited properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I searched the threads on here and found multiple similar posts but no solutions

Assume I have a User table in my db that I've mapped to a simple User entity

```
public class User{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
}
```

I want to create a new class that will encapsulate an ExternalUser which has all the same fields as User but adds a few more fields. The fields for my ExternalUser will be populated from a view in the db that pulls in both the fields from User and the additional fields required for ExternalUser

```
public class ExternalUser : User{
    public int SomeExternalId{get;set;};
    public string SomeExternalProp{get;set;};
}
```

but no matter how I seem to define my mappings for this new object I get the following error:

The property 'UserId' is not a declared property on type 'ExternalUser'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

Can someone share the correct way to map this. Its stuff like this that makes me hate EF, simply inheriting a POCO shouldn't cause it to blow up, especially not when all the fields exist in the underlying view that I'm pointing to. Much thanks!

Comment: can you show a "not working" mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your use case but if you have the option to make `User` an `abstract` base `class`, then you can use the [Table per Concrete Type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) approach.

You would need to make `User` an `abstract` class and call `MapInheritedProperties()` when creating the model mappings for `ExternalUser`:

```
public abstract class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

[Table("ExternalUser")]
public class ExternalUser : User
{
    public int SomeExternalId { get; set; }
    public string SomeExternalProp { get; set; }
}
```

*Note that I am using `[Table]` attribute to map the entity name to table name (you can also do this in `OnModelCreating` method but I find it cleaner to use the `[Table]` attribute):*

And this is `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    // I believe the inherited properties are mapped by default 
    modelBuilder.Entity<ExternalUser>().Map(m => 
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
    });
}
```

*Note that I am removing `PluralizingTableNameConvention` as I don't want plural table names.*